# Escaping PHP code inside JavaScript onmouseover

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have difficulties in understanding how to manage single and double quotes inside a JavaScript event inside a php block.

This is the code:

```
<?php
$mainImagePath = '';
$galleryImages = $this->getGalleryImages();
if (count($galleryImages) > 0) {
    $gallery = '<div class="more-views">';
    $gallery .= '<h2>' . $this->__('More Views') . '</h2>';
    $gallery .= '<ul>';
    foreach ($galleryImages as $_image) {
        if ($_image->getFile() == $_product->getData('small_image')) {
            $mainImagePath = $this->getGalleryUrl($_image);
        }
        $gallery .= '<li>'
                 .  '<a href="' . $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()) . '" '
                 .  'rel="popupWin:\'' . $this->getGalleryUrl($_image) . '\', useZoom: \'cloudZoom\', smallImage: \'' . $this->getCloudImage($this->getProduct(), $_image) .  '\'" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" title="' . $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) . '" onmouseover="$(\'image\').src = "'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(256).'"; return false;">'
                 .  '<img src="' . $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56) . '" width="56" height="56" alt="' . $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) . '" />'
                 .  '</a></li>';
    }
    $gallery .= '</ul></div>'; 
}
?>
```

The problem is the `onmouseover` event, which has a `.src` method that expects the value to be inside double quotes, but putting double quotes inside that string breaks the rest.

I already tried putting the needed value in a variable and echoing the variable, but that didn't work either.

How can I correctly escape quotes there?

Comment: Don't try. Drop out of PHP mode to output static HTML, and bind JS event listeners with `addEventListener` (or a compatibility library). Don't use intrinsic event handlers. Trying to embed JS in HTML in PHP is just a nightmare of nesting and escaping. Avoid the maintenance headache, don't do it.

Comment: To paraphrase, "It hurts when I do that" => then don't do that.

Comment: I know it's a nightmare, but this comes from a Magento module and the only thing i was trying to insert was the mouseover event, i wouldn't have chosen this way of writing that piece of code myself. Thanks for explanations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onmouseover="$(\'image\').src = "'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(256).'"; return false;">
```

use single quote

```
onmouseover="$(\'image\').src = \''.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(256).'\'; return false;">
```

Comment: I chose this solution because it's the most straightforward one. Thank you so much, it makes me angry that it's always about little details..

Answer (score 1):

I would recommended writing out the html / javascript first and then simply echo the php vars into their correct places. You will not have to do any escaping and it makes for more maintainable code.

Your IDE will also be able to correctly apply syntax highlighting

```
<?php

$mainImagePath = '';
$galleryImages = $this->getGalleryImages();

?>
<?php if(count($galleryImages) > 0) { ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('More Views'); ?></h2>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($galleryImages as $_image) { ?>
            <?php 

            if ($_image->getFile() == $_product->getData('small_image')) {
                $mainImagePath = $this->getGalleryUrl($_image);
            }

            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" rel="popupWin:'<?php echo $this->getGalleryUrl($_image); ?>', useZoom: 'cloudZoom', smallImage: '<?php echo $this->getCloudImage($this->getProduct(), $_image); ?>'" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()); ?>" onmouseover="$('image').src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(256); ?>"; return false;">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56) ;?>" width="56" height="56" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()); ?>">
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest to use the `if (condition): ?> … <?php endif; ?>` syntax for more clarity.